# Clojure - Issue with multiple sends in a row

Tags: clojure

I have run into some very odd behavior with an agent and the send function. I have boiled down the behavior to a small amount of code.

This code:

```
(defn weird-behavior
  []
  (let [my-agent (agent {:entries nil})]
    (doseq [entry [1 2 3]]
      (send my-agent assoc :entries (conj (@my-agent :entries) entry)))
    (Thread/sleep 100) ;; Allow time for the sends to finish
    (println my-agent)))
```

Outputs:

```
#<Agent@222e8b4: {:entries (3)}>
```

However if I give it 10 milliseconds in between each call to send like so:

```
(defn weird-behavior
  []
  (let [my-agent (agent {:entries nil})]
    (doseq [entry [1 2 3]]
      (send my-agent assoc :entries (conj (@my-agent :entries) entry))
      (Thread/sleep 10)))
    (Thread/sleep 100) ;; Allow time for the sends to finish
    (println my-agent)))
```

The output is as expected:

```
#<Agent@6211e63b: {:entries (3 2 1)}>
```

Why is this happening? How can I send multiple items in a row into an agent?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is you are `deref`erencing the agent outside the action, so when passing the agent's current value as an argument to `send`, all actions queued for the agent receive the same value (i.e. `nil`).

You can use `update-in` to avoid having to `deref`erence the value:

```clj
(defn weird-behavior
  []
  (let [my-agent (agent {:entries nil})]
    (doseq [entry [1 2 3]]
      (send my-agent update-in [:entries] conj entry))
    (Thread/sleep 100) ;; Allow time for the sends to finish
    (println my-agent)))

;= #<Agent@1a69a9c: {:entries (3 2 1)}>
```

Answer (score 1):

The dispatch action of `send` is a function of the current state of the agent. It might help to make this explicit so you aren't tempted to attempt the dereference it yourself.

```
(defn weird-behavior []
  (let [my-agent (agent {:entries nil})]
    (doseq [entry [1 2 3]]
      (send my-agent 
            (fn [state] 
              (merge-with conj state {:entries entry}))))
      (await my-agent)
      (println my-agent)))
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem can be illustrated by having the function you are sending to the agent print the value it is going to append. If instead of just calling `assoc` you compose this with a println so it prints the value then you can clearly see the difference between the functions with and without the sleep:

```
(let [my-agent (agent {:entries nil})]                                                                                                                                    
  (doseq [entry [1 2 3]]                                                                                                                                                  
    (send my-agent (comp #(do (println "adding entry" %) %)                                                                                                               
                         assoc)                                                                                                                                           
          :entries (conj (@my-agent :entries) entry)))                                                                                                                    
  (Thread/sleep 100) ;; Allow time for the sends to finish                                                                                                                
  (println my-agent)) 

adding entry {:entries (1)}                                                                                                                                               
adding entry {:entries (2)}                                                                                                                                               
adding entry {:entries (3)}                                                                                                                                               
#<Agent@75bee6fc: {:entries (3)}>
```

vs  the version with the sleep:

```
(let [my-agent (agent {:entries nil})]                                                                                                                                    
  (doseq [entry [1 2 3]]                                                                                                                                                  
    (send my-agent (comp #(do (println "adding entry" %) %)                                                                                                               
                         assoc)                                                                                                                                           
          :entries (conj (@my-agent :entries) entry))                                                                                                                     
    (Thread/sleep 10))                                                                                                                                                    
  (Thread/sleep 100) ;; Allow time for the sends to finish                                                                                                                
  (println my-agent)) 

adding entry {:entries (1)}                                                                                                                                               
adding entry {:entries (2 1)}                                                                                                                                             
adding entry {:entries (3 2 1)}                                                                                                                                           
#<Agent@1c36ee92: {:entries (3 2 1)}>
```

This makes it clear that **all three calls are reading the state of the agent, then all three are adding to the value they read** independently of each other.